# Integrating Tumblr with Wordpress

Tags: tumblr

I have a project where I have to integrate my clients Tumblr into a Wordpress page. The idea is on the category page, the posts should show up in a Masonry format. Once you click a post it goes to the Tumblr format (Users like this, Users reblogged this).
How will I go about doing this preferably without a plugin. Thanks!

Comment: I have created a custom Tumblr theme, but I would love if it is possible to integrate the Tumblr code into Wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You can use tumblr's platform instead of wordpress.

First, you need to learn how to create a custom theme:
http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes

Then you can add David DeSandro's neat, masonry API which allows you to control a whole bunch of properties. Though it is a Jquery plugin but not limited to wordpress, thus having the ability to adapt to any CMS / blogging platform. http://masonry.desandro.com/

Or,

if lazy, you can download a masonry looking theme on themefroest :)
Have fun.